# How to convert one type of object array into another?

Tags: swift

I have two classes **Grade** & **Teacher**.

```
class Grade: NSObject {

    var grade:String = ""
    var id:String = ""

    init(from dictionary:Parameters) {

        self.grade = dictionary["grade"] as? String ?? ""
        self.id = dictionary["grade_id"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}

class Teacher: NSObject {

    var teacher:String = ""
    var id:String = ""

    init(from dictionary:Parameters) {

        self.teacher = dictionary["teacher"] as? String ?? ""
        self.id = dictionary["teacher_id"] as? String ?? ""
    }
}
```

So I want to create a common classes which will id & title. It can take data from both classes.

I am using below approach but I don't think it is best way to implement. Let me know what could be the best way.

```
   func prepareDataSourceForPicker(pickerType:PickerType) {

        var pickerArr = [PickerItem]()
        if pickerType == .grade {

            for value in self.arrGrades {
                let pickerItem:PickerItem = PickerItem()
                pickerItem.title = value.grade
                pickerItem.id = value.id
                pickerArr.append(pickerItem)
            }

        } else if pickerType == .teacher {
            for value in self.arrTeachers {
                let pickerItem:PickerItem = PickerItem()
                pickerItem.title = value.teacher
                pickerItem.id = value.id
                pickerArr.append(pickerItem)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you can take advantage of protocol here as swift is protocol oriented language make one protocol and make both class to conform that protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a protocol called `PickerItemProtocol`:

```
protocol PickerItemProtocol {
    var title: String { get }
    var id: String { get }
}
```

Then conform `Grade` and `Teacher` to it:

```
extension Grade: PickerItemProtocol {
    var title: String { return grade }
}

extension Teacher : PickerItemProtocol {
    var title: String { return teacher }
}
```

Now in `prepareDataSourceForPicker` you can do this:

```
func prepareDataSourceForPicker(pickerType:PickerType) {

    let dataSource: [PickerItemProtocol]
    switch pickerType {
        case .grade: dataSource = self.arrGrades
        case .teacher: dataSource = self.arrTeachers 
    }
    let pickerArr = dataSource.map { item in
        let pickerItem = PickerItem()
        pickerItem.title = item.title
        pickerItem.id = item.id
        return pickerItem
    }
    // you might want to do something with pickerArr here...
}
```

Comment: why you have written   pickerItem.title = item.teacher what about grades ?

Comment: @Techiee Oops! That's a copy-paste error. Fixed now.

Comment: why you have given only title in extension why not id?

Comment: @Techiee Because both of your classes already have an `id` property.

Comment: both my classes have title as well but still you did not create a new property as id. Is It because you these property is common among both classes

Comment: @Techiee Neither `Grade` nor `Teacher` have a property called `title`. `Grade` has a `grade` property while `Teacher` has a `teacher`  property. That's why defined a `title` for them in the extensions. I don't need to rewrite `id` again because `Grade` and `Teacher` already have that.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way of doing this is in the most basic concept of OOP i.e inheritance. What i mean is:

1. Create a BaseModel class having basic attributes (common attributes that you wants in the every child class). in your case it is type, id and title.
2. Then make teacher and grade to subclass of it and add the remaining properties to each class(teacher and grade).
3. Then simply you will have type, id and title in both teacher and grade model.