# How to convert object into another object

Tags: arrays, swift, oop

How i convert an object 1 into object 2 that have additional properties

```
class Object1 {
   var imageUrl: String
   var title: String
   var description: String
   var order: Int
}

class Object2 {
   var imageUrl: String
   var title: String
   var description: String
   var buttonTitle: String
   var pageType: OnboardingType
}
```

What i'm trying so far is this

```
var items: [Object1] = []

var items2: [Object2] = [] {
    return convertItems(items: items)
}

private func convertItems(items: [Object1]) -> [Object2] {
        var object2Item: [Object2] = []

        items.forEach { item in
            if item.order == 1 {
                object2Item.append(Object2(imageUrl: item.imageUrl, title: item.title, description: item.description, buttonTitle: nil, onboardingType: .hajj))
            } else if item.order == 2 {
                object2Item.append(Object2(imageUrl: item.imageUrl, title: item.title, description: item.description, buttonTitle: nil, onboardingType: .hajj))
            } else if item.order == 3 {
                object2Item.append(Object2(imageUrl: item.imageUrl, title: item.title, description: item.description, buttonTitle: "some text".localized, onboardingType: .hajj))
            }
            
        }
      return object2Item
    }
```

i have seen this in another stackoverflow post with protocol [protoco model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51183795/how-to-convert-one-type-of-object-array-into-another), but i can't get how to additional properties if i use protocol as an object type

Comment: You have any number of possible ways you might achieve this - what is the particular issue with your current workflow?

Comment: it was crash when i get the array, my array is an onboarding slider using a scrollView. when i check the item it was there, but the crash say i have an index out of range. @MadProgrammer

Comment: Then the problem probably isn't with the conversation workflow, but with how you're managing the data, but I'm just guessing

Comment: @ferryawijayanto If I had to guess (and I do have to guess, because you haven't shown the relevant code), you're making the assumption that the result of `convertItems(items:)` has the same size as its input `items`, but it isn''t because there are `item.order` values other than `1`, `2` or `3`, which got silently ignored and never got appended into `object2Item`.

Comment: no the size always the same, the item always have 3 item. i got it in backend, but somehow the index is out of range @Alexander

Comment: Well there's nothing I can really do about that with the information you've provided

Comment: your answer is correct by the way, like what you said. the information i give is not fully explain, since it's my company code i can't expose it.

Comment: @ferryawijayanto you should make a minimal reproducible example. Not just because it helps people understand your problem, but because it helps *you* understand the problem. I would guess that of all the issues I’ve had that I was about to post about on SO, we’ll over half I’ve figured out myself in the process of making a minimal reproducible example. It gets you to think, simplify, and question assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're question is tagged [oop], so I'll answer from that perspective.

You should avoid treating objects as dumb groups of data, that isn't what OOP is about. Aggregating related fields into records of some kind has predated OOP by decades. OOP is about polymorphism: having objects respond to the same message in different ways, such that all of the users of the objects don't have to manually check its type. I don't see anything in your sample that would benefit much from polymorphism yet.

Objects are intended to model things. I don't know what things you're modelling in this example (`Object1` and `Object2` don't really communicate much intent, if you see what I mean).

The "correct" OOP solution here is to name your objects after the things they model. If you need to model a transformation from one thing to another, than that transformation should have a name inspired from the business domain. For example, a `SalesLead` object might turn into a `CustomerObject` by virtue of a `saleCompleted` method. Or a `DownloadingFile` might have a `downloadeCompleted` method that returns a `File`. Etc.

If you provide more context to your problem, I can make this suggestion more tailor made, but for now, I would start with something like:

```
extension Object1 {
    init(from object1: Object) { // FIXME: Give a meaningful name
        let buttonTitle: String?

        switch object1.order {
        case 1, 2: buttonTitle = nil
        case 3: buttonTitle = "some text".localized
        default: fatalError("Not implemented")
        }

        self.init(
            imageUrl: object1.imageUrl,
            title: object1.title,
            description: object1.description,
            buttonTitle: buttonTitle,
            pageType: .hajj,
        )
    }
}

private func convertItems(items: [Object1]) -> [Object2] { // FIXME: Give a meaningful name
    items.map(Object2.init(from:))
}
```